# php-mongodb: In PHP, how do I fetch an array stored in monogdb?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

Can somebody please tell me where/what I'm doing it wrong and how the conversion should take place? I'm new to PHP and MongoDB so please excuse my naivety...

This is my document in mongo:
`{ "_id" : "x", "links" : [1,2,3] }`

In PHP, I do this:
`foreach($cur as $obj)
echo $obj['_id'] . "-->" . $obj['links']`

My output is:
`x-->Array`
instead of this:
`x-->1,2,3`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add clarification to the above answer.. what he's doing is really taking an array and casting it into a string with a ',' as a separator.. since the $obj is coming down as an array you would need to cycle through it (unless you're fine displaying it as such).

```
foreach($obj['links'] as $link){
   //do something
}
```

This way you're keeping it in an array format rather than using an operation to cast it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $obj['_id'] . "-->" .  implode(',',$obj['links']);
```

Comment: awesome! it works great. can you also tell me what I should do to store them in a separate array at my application layer?

Comment: dont worry about it, casting it to an array worked! thanks a lot again!

Comment: All right, `$a=$obj['links'];`(makes a copy of the array) and `$a=&$obj['links'];` (references the original array)